# Playwright TypeScript getByRole Method Adding Case Insensitivity Regex

Tags: typescript, testing, playwright

I'm using the new 1.27 update getByRole API Locators in my tests.

My page contains a form with two Checkboxes that contain the values:

- "Don't know"
- "Don't Know"

At run time my test fails due to finding two elements

```
 strict mode violation: "role=checkbox[name="Don't know"i]" resolved to 2 elements:
```

Is there a way to switch the case insensitivity regex off?

My current Locator:

```
dontKnowCheckbox: Locator = this.page.getByRole('checkbox', { name: 'Don\'t know' });
```

Comment: Can you share both HTML checkbox element please?

Comment: And would you Accept a xpath instead of css selector?

Comment: Hi @JakyRuby , I do have workarounds to interacting with this element, such as 
   dontKnowCheckbox1: Locator = this.page.getByText('Don\'t know', { exact: true });
But was interested in exploring the new features and their limitations - HTML Below:
 <input type="checkbox" id="1589e6e9-e7ec-4ea0-bbb2-1580645ade33-Don't know" class="control-input__Input-sc-1lgniz-1 bMjanG" value="Don't know">
<label for="1589e6e9-e7ec-4ea0-bbb2-1580645ade33-Don't know" class="text__Text-sc-1u9gciq-0 hVeePB">Don't know</label>

Comment: ANd did it work with your know approach? I do not understand what you mean with "exploring the new features and their limitations"

Comment: @JakyRuby Yes it does, as getByText has a case sensitivity switch.
BUT, i would prefer to use getByRole and would like to know if there's any way to remove the case insensitivity from that method

Comment: `getByRole` support regex: `https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-page#page-get-by-role` Try to send a regex here: `dontKnowCheckbox: Locator = this.page.getByRole('checkbox', { name: regex });` in that regex can say insensitive

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the typescript definition for getByRole, i see you can add the exact parameter in the options object:

```
dontKnowCheckbox: Locator = this.page.getByRole('checkbox', { name: 'Don\'t know', exact: true });
```

Exact defaults to false (case insensitive), but if you pass true then it'll be case sensitive.